# How to prove that $f(x)=x\cdot |x|$ is one-to-one?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

I know that $f(x)$ is one-to-one if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$, or, equivalently, $x_1\neq x_2\implies f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Visually, it is clear that $x|x|$ is one-to-one, but I am struggling to derive a proof from the definition. What is the best way to approach this problem? Would re-writing $x|x|$ in another form help at all?

Comment: Observe that if $x\geq 0$ then $f(x)\geq 0$. And vice versa, if $x<0$ then $f(x)<0$. Therefore $f$ is injective if and only if it is injective when restricted to $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$, separately. And for those intervals the formula simplifies, we can get rid of absolute value.

Comment: $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&x\ge 0\\-x^2&x<0\end{cases}$

Comment: Can you see that $f$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: Yes, I intuitively understand that $f$ is strictly increasing. How can I apply this to my proof?

Comment: A key idea implicit in the answer and the comments: This is a proof-by-cases. One way to see why that is a good proof structure to adopt for this problem is that the absolute value function itself is a definition-by-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we divide domain in two parts, $x\geq 0$ and $x<0$, it is easy to note that no range value is common for these two parts. If we show injection on each part, we are done.

For $x\geq 0, f(x)=x^2$.

Then for $a,b\geq 0$, we have,

$f(a)=f(b)\implies a^2=b^2\implies a=b$.

Finish argument for part $x<0$.

Comment: So we don't need to consider $a\geq 0$ and $b<0$?

Comment: In this case of course you will never have $a=b$ ...

Comment: @Lachlan04 I have edited answer to clarify your point.